# npm shows warning "The following package was not found and will be installed"

Tags: npm

What is the reasoning behind following warning?

```
npm WARN exec The following package was not found and will be installed: next@14.0.1
```

Also see full output here: https://github.com/fraunhofer-isi/micat/actions/runs/6706850723/job/18224128304

How can the package be installed if it has not been found?

=> Is it a bug in the message and the "not" should be removed by npm?

=> Or can a package be installed by npm, even if it has not been found?

=> How to resolve the warning?

Comment: To me it seems that the library was not found in your local `node_modules` folder and it'll be installed from the web.